# Getting recent selection in multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to populate content depending upon the multiple select box selection.
I can get all selected value of select box.
Using

```
$('select').change(function(){
   console.info($(this).val()) // it gives me array
});
```

But i want only the recent selection/deselection user makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// this will set the last selected or deselected option element's value to the select element as a custom attribute "recent" 
$("#selectEl option").click(function(event) {
   $(this).parent().attr("recent", $(this).val());
});


$("#selectEl").attr("recent"); // returns the last selected/deselected option value or undefined if attribute recent is not present
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
function arr_diff(a1, a2) {
    var a = [],
        diff = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
    a[a1[i]] = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)
    if (a[a2[i]]) delete a[a2[i]];
    else a[a2[i]] = true;
    for (var k in a)
    diff.push(k);
    return diff;
}
var oldSelect = [];
$('select').change(function() {
    var changes = arr_diff(oldSelect, $(this).val());
    console.info(changes); // it gives me array
    oldSelect = $(this).val();
});
```

changes contains only the selcted/deselected element

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/j5rBS/

Answer (score 0):

or, **Simply** just get the first index of array while select.

```
$(function(){
$('select').change(function(){
   var opt=$(this).val();
    $("span").text(opt[0]);
});
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMw92/10/

Comment: This will not give me recent selection, I gives first value from selection.